# How to filter select with multiple properties?

Tags: angularjs

I have a select in my angular app:

```
 {{editMode}}
      <select ng-model="item.solCategory" class="form-input form-dropdown cols-6 margin-bottom-10"
              ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories| filter:{category.available:'true',editMode:'true'} "
              ng-change="changeSelection(item)"
              required>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
      </select>
```

I tried to filter the categories and works with one property ie category.available. This is a property on the categories array. Now I would like to filter on a scope variable in addition to that. This variable is called editMode boolean. When I try the statement above I get an error. How can I fix this? This is the error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 29 of the expression [categories| filter:{category.available:'true',editMode:'true'}] starting at [.available:'true',editMode:'true'}].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with a function:

```
<"... | filter: myFilter">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(category) {
  return $scope.editMode && category.available;
}
```

But in your case it would be more efficient to simply prevent the whole directive to be computed if you are not in inputMode, using `ngIf`:

```
<select ng-if="editMode" ng-options="....">
```

Answer (score 0):

the error comes from calling the property category.available
you can write it like this:

```
category as category.name for category in categories| filter:{available:'true'}| filter :{editMode:'true'}
```